# Spring JNDI lookup EJB Timer Service

Tags: java, spring, timer, ejb

Is there a way in a Spring bean configuration to lookup the EJB timer service thro JNDI?

Actually, is there a way to use spring bean config to inject the EJB container's timer service into my objects?

I would like my spring config to document as much as possible all the beans/objects being used in my app.

Also, getting the session context directly (for the ejb timer) violates security protocol.

#### Appendix:

Please don't tell me how to do jndi lookup. I am asking if I did a jndi lookup, since my config is already doing jndi lookup for other stuffs, is there a jndi that spring web has already preconfig'd for the timer?

I want to know perhaps, if spring web has a way to interact with ejb, whereby I could either get the timer thro jndi inquiry or thro any spring factory beans.

It does not have to be a jndi lookup.

Comment: Do you mean this `@Resource TimerService timerService;` ?

Comment: Yes. (comments must be at least 15 chars in length, silly)

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you need now. You can take a look into `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, which has `setJndiFactory` option, which actually is used to resolve `@Resource` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. If you know JNDI name of that object you can use:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="timer" jndi-name="TIMER_JNDI_NAME"/>
```

See more info in the [Spring Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee)

The result of such component will be a Spring Bean, which you can simply inject to any other your beans.

Regarding docs: you can use `<description>` sub-element for `<bean>`s

Comment: Please don't tell me how to use jndi lookup. That is not the question.